# Cassandra Data modelling with multiple tables for same data

Tags: cassandra, datamodel

Cassandra Data Modeling Query
Hello,

The data model i am working on is as below with different tables for same data data set for satisfying different kinds of query. The data mainly stores event data of some campaigns sent out on multiple channels like email, web, mobile app, sms etc. Events can include page visits, email opens, link clicks etc for different subscribers.

Table 1:

```
(enterprise_id int, domain_id text, campaign_id int, event_category text, event_action text, datetime timestamp, subscription_id text, event_label text, ........) (many more columns not part of primary key)

PRIMARY KEY ((enterprise_id,campaign_id),domain_id, event_category, event_action, datetime, subscription_id))

CLUSTERING ORDER BY (domain_id DESC, event_category DESC, event_action DESC, datetime DESC, subscription_id DESC)
```

Keys and Data size for Table 1:

I have partition key as enterprise_id + campaign_id . Each enterprise can have several campaigns . The datastore may have data for few hundred campaigns. Each campaign can have upto 2-3 million records. Hence there may be 3000 partitions across 100 enterprises and each partition having 2-3 miilion records.

Cassandra Queries: Query always with partition key + primary key including the datetime field. The subscription id is included in primary key to keep each record unique as we can have multiple records with similar values for rest of the keys in primary key. enterprise_id +c ampaign_id is always available as a filter in the queries.

Table 2:

```
(enterprise_id int, domain_id text, event_category text, event_action text, datetime timestamp, subscription_id text, event_label text, campaign_id int........) (many more columns not part of primary key)

PRIMARY KEY (enterprise_id, domain_id, event_category, event_action, datetime, subscription_id))

CLUSTERING ORDER BY (domain_id DESC, event_category DESC, event_action DESC, datetime DESC, subscription_id DESC)
```

Keys and Data size for Table 2) : I have partition key as enterprise_id only. Each enterprise can have several campaigns . May be few hundred campaigns. Each campaign can have upto 2-3 Mn records. In this case the partition is quite big with data for all campaigns in a single partition. can have upto 800 - 900 million entries

Cassandra Queries: Query always with partition key + primary key upto datetime. The subscription id is included in primary key to keep each record unique as we can have multiple records with similar values for rest of the keys in primary key. In this case, data has to be queries across campaigns and we may not have campaign_id as a filter in the queries.

Table 3:

```
(enterprise_id int, subscription_id text, domain_id text, event_category text, event_action text, datetime timestamp, event_label text, campaign_id int........) (many more columns not part of primary key)

PRIMARY KEY (enterprise_id, subscription_id, domain_id, event_category, event_action, datetime, ))

CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( subscription_id DESC, domain_id DESC, event_category DESC, event_action DESC, datetime DESC,)
```

Keys and Data size for Table 3) : I have partition key as enterprise_id. Each enterprise can have several campaigns . May be few hundred campaigns. Each campaign can have upto 2-3 Mn records. In this case the partition is quite big with data for all campaigns in a single partition. can have upto 800 -900 million entries

Cassandra Queries: Query always with partition key + primary key as subscription_id only. Should be able to query directly on enterprise_id + subscription_id.

My Queries:

1. Size of data on each partition: With Table 2) and Table 3) i may end up with more than 800 -900 million rows per partition. As per my reading it is not ok to have so many entries per partition. How can i achieve my use case in this scenario? Even if i create multiple partitions based on some data like a week_number (1-52 in a year), the query will need to query across all partitions and end up using a IN clause with all week numbers which is as good as scanning all data.
2. Is it ok to have multiple tables with same partition key and different primary keys with Clustering order change? For example in Table 2 and Table 3 the hash will be on enterprise_id and will lead to same node. However only the clustering key order has changed and will allow me to query directly on the required key. Will the data be in different physical partitions for Table2 and Table3 in such a scenario? Or if it maps to same partition number how will cassandra internally distinguish between the two tables?
3. Is it ok to use ALLOW FILTERING if i specify the partition key. For example i can avoid the need for creating Table 3 and use table 2 for query on subscription_id directly if i use ALLOW FILTERING on Table 2. What will be the impact again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please only as one question per question.  Given the length and detail required for your answers, this post is unlikely to provide long term value for future users.

> As per my reading it is not ok to have so many entries per partition. How can I achieve my use case in this scenario?

Unfortunately, if partitioning on a time component will not work, then you'll have to find some other column to partition the data by.  I've seen rows-per-partition work ok in the range of 50k to 20k.  Most of those use cases on the higher end had small partitions.  It looks like your model has many columns, so I'd be curious as to the average partition size.  Essentially, find a column to partition on which keeps your partition sizes in the 10MB to 1MB range.

> Is it ok to have multiple tables with same partition key and different primary keys with Clustering order change?

Yes, this is perfectly fine.

> Will the data be in different physical partitions for Table2 and Table3 in such a scenario? Or if it maps to same partition number how will cassandra internally distinguish between the two tables?

The partition is hashed into a number ranging from +/- 2^63.  That number will then be compared to the partition ranges mapped to all nodes, and then the query will be sent to that node.  So all the partition does, is determine which node is responsible for the data.

The tables have their data files written to different directories, based on table name.  So Cassandra distinguishes between the tables by the table name provided in the query.  Nothing you need to worry about.

> Is it ok to use ALLOW FILTERING if I specify the partition key.

I would still recommend against it if you're concerned about performance.  But the *good* thing about using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive *while* specifying a full partition key, will indeed prevent Cassandra from reading multiple nodes to build the result set.  So that *should* be ok.  The only drawback here, is that Cassandra stores/reads data from disk by the defined `CLUSTERING ORDER`, and using `ALLOW FILTERING` obviously complicates that process (forcing random reads vs. sequential reads).

Comment: Thank You @Aaron for your inputs. If partition key only helps in identifying the node where data shall to be saved and within a node we have different folders for different tables, what is the maximum number of Rows per table or data size we can have per table in a given node.